# Mapping a text response in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

Initializing the state

```
this.state = {
apiResponse : []
}
```

setting the state to response from api inside componentDidmount

```
this.setState({
 apiResponse: response
})
```

"response" looks like

```
{polyinfo: "{"name": "hello1"}"}
{polyinfo: "{"name": "hello2"}"}
```

I need to get the value of name

Things i tried

```
list = () => {

const polyInfo = JSON.parse(this.state.apiResponseJson);
return polyInfo.map(element => {
console.log(element.name);
  // console.log(element.polyinfo.name);
});
```

};

Comment: Doesn't look like a valid json

Comment: Edited just to be clear

Comment: try https://jsonlint.com/ to check if json is correct

Comment: 2 errors I can see: the response value contains 2 json objects. Put them into one object by adding a { and a } at the beginning and at the end. Also the use of " is wrong: you have to use ' inside " or vice versa. Then check it with jsonlint as kelvin said. The second error is this.state.apiResponseJson. Correct is: this.state.apiResponse.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you forgot to add a comma at the end of the first line in

```
{polyinfo: "{"name": "hello1"}"}
{polyinfo: "{"name": "hello2"}"}
```

but assuming that this was typed as a valid array, the correct way to access name here would be

```
const parsedContainer = JSON.parse(this.state.apiResponse[i].polyinfo) //where "i" is the //array index
console.log(parsedContainer.name) //logging the name to the console
```

this works because we are parsing the string type json from polyinfo and parsing it into json that javascript can read and then we are using that parsed json to read the name property.

Comment: I recommend json parse with try/catch. all json data are not stable.

Comment: I disagree. there is really no point in using try catch for this purpose, because as we can see, all of the json data is 100% valid json.